# MAP v.s. Sampling in Bayesian Problem

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

I've got a high dimensional Bayesian inversion problem. I've managed to solve the MAP with gradient descent method. I'm struggling to use sampling method to solve the same problem.

I wonder does the bayesian model (priors and likelihood) works for MAP solver should always work for sampling method such as MCMC? I could not prove that, but in this particular problem, I found MCMC is not able to converging or very difficult to converge while gradient descent works well finding the MAP.

Comment: Finding the MAP is not a Bayesian action as (a) it only returns a value, with no measure of uncertainty and (b) it depends on the [choice of the dominating measure.](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/tag/dominating-measure/) It is more accurate to describe a MAP estimate as a penalised maximum likelihood estimate.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the inaccurate description. It is penalized maximum likelihood estimate. I understand that it is not a Bayesian action, but the cost function is formulated by Bayesian, thus I'm trying to ask whether it is somehow connected with statistical sampling? Given the penalized maximum likelihood estimation, does it help to prove the model is good for sampling operations?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by "solving the MAP with gradient descent method" you mean that gradient descent has found *some* solution. The major difference between optimization and simulation is that optimization tries to find single optimum (minimum or maximum) of the function, while simulation tries to explore the possible outcomes of a function. In both cases you can get stuck in local modes. So the fact that one optimization algorithm with some particular set of hyperparameters has found some solution does not mean that other optimization algorithm, or other set of hyperparameters will lead to same solution, or that some simulation algorithm, with some set of parameters will.

On another hand, if you want to assume that the optimization algorithm is guaranteed to find the global minima, and assume that the simulation algorithm will adequately sample large number of values, from a broad range of possible outcomes of the target distribution, then the answer would be: yes, the mode of the simulations should agree with the mode found by optimization algorithm. But this is the perfect case, not the real-life outcomes, that can differ.

Comment: Hi, yes. I mean I found the MAP solution by an optimization process. However the cost function for optimization procedure is based on Bayesian model, thus optimization found the solution maximize the posterior. As you said the optimization only find one solution, thus I want to test the same bayesian model with sampling/simulation. And I expect the MCMC sampling give me some results confirms the optimization results. However, as I mentioned, I found the MCMC chain had problem converge given same prior, likelihood. Thus comes the question

Comment: @user3289737 yes, it can happen. What exactly is your question? You should possibly try different parameters for the sampler, or different MCMC algorithm. Also, if the sampler has stuck, I would wonder if the optimizer didn't have similar problems.

Comment: I adjust the prior distribution so that the optimization procedure works well. So I used the same prior for MCMC and found it hard to converge. I'm wondering does it mean it is the sampler's problem only. Or it is possible that I might need fine tune the prior assumption accordingly.

Comment: @user3289737 priors is not something that you tune so that the algorithm works. Such problems do not prove anything, they only show that some algorithm, in some particular setting has problems. Maybe you need different parameters for the algorithm, or need more iterations, or different algorithm etc.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I think now I got my fundamental question clearer. The idea is that I have a gaussian prior but not knowing the deviations. However, the prior also serves as the regularize for the optimization procedure and I found certain range of deviation works better without over-fitting or under-fitting. Thus I start to confuse myself whether the prior from optimization should work for MCMC.

Comment: @user3289737 what about using hyperpriors for the deviations?

Comment: You are right, I should have prior of the deviations. I was just trying hard to make the connection between the two approaches. Thank you for sharing